# iptables: Routing requests to localhost:8080 to google.com

Tags: unix, iptables

I am trying a simple routing rule that would forward the requests to localhost:8080 to some external address (ex google).

I added the following rule :

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d localhost --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 173.194.67.139:80
```

The rule appears first in the chain :

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination      
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             localhost            tcp dpt:http-alt to:173.194.67.139:80
```

But the requests are not redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Netfilter module (iptables) doesn't operate at the [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer). If you could redirect HTTP packets to a Google IP address, they wouldn't have the correct `Host:` header. For what you want to accomplish, you'd be better off configuring a proxy server. Examples of web proxy servers available for Unix systems include Apache (with `mod_proxy`), Nginx, and Squid.